# How do I split the lines of two polygons that are stuck together?

Tags: qgis, polygon, line, editing

When using the tool to move/delete/add points, all the lines (from multiple polygons) connected to a point move at the same time. Though sometimes this is prefered, there are times I want to move the lines from those polygons seperately. Is there a key/tool that can help me with this?

I'm using QGIS

Comment: Without knowing witch software you're using it's impossible to help...

Comment: sorry, added that I use QGIS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have topological editing turned on, try to turn it off.

There is a button on the snapping toolbar (the one that have a magnet icon) to do just that (see picture)

[image]

or read more on [topological editing](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html#topological-editing)